# SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists - How to bound certificate to ipport?

Tags: cmd, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, netsh

I'm trying to execute this command in CMD:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=‎89857a42309423c239f42392384a appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-13123454a52b}
```

and got error message:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that
> file already exists.

How to add certificate to ipport if the certificate has already been added?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It means that the port has already bounded a certificate. If we want to bound new certificate we need to delete the old one and bound new one.

1. Check if port has bounded a cert:

   `netsh http show sslcert > c:\result.txt`
2. Open the result.txt and search for the port (in my case 443)
3. Delete the old certificate:
   `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443`
4. Bound new certificate

   `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=‎89857a42309423c239f42392384a appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-13123454a52b}`

Comment: BTW, to delete: netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443

Comment: For SNI sites: `netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport=hostname:443`