# SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183, Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: iis, deployment, ssl-certificate, netsh

Below error prevents deployment of my web application on IIS.

Exact error msg:

```
2023-01-10T09:37:12.3948952Z ##[command]"netsh" http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:460
2023-01-10T09:37:12.4640383Z ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:460 certhash=*** appid={2f458-f070-403b-bb53-5e35ff05701} certstorename=MY
2023-01-10T09:37:12.4983107Z 
2023-01-10T09:37:12.4983504Z SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
2023-01-10T09:37:12.4988896Z Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

I tried as mentioned in few of stack overflow answers.

In Netsh, I tried deleting the old certificate if already bounded, but says deletion failed, and cant find file.

```
netsh>http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:460

SSL Certificate deletion failed, Error: 2
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: As only IIS 8 and above is supported by Microsoft, you should try very best to avoid adding IP based certificate mappings. Stick to SNI based mappings please, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings

Comment: @LexLi A new certificate was created by IT recently (for my web application). I believe they have done IP based mapping. This is my first deployment after the new certificate, which results in this error. With old certificate, the deployment was fine. I would appreciate if you could let me know how I can proceed in this scenario.

Comment: You can ignore the old IP based mapping and add SNI based mappings. The latter takes higher priority so should work flawlessly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About adding an SSL certificate, you can refer to [netsh-http#add-sslcert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http#add-sslcert) and [netsh-http#delete-sslcert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http#delete-sslcert). There are examples in the documentation for reference.

"The system cannot find the file specified." means that there weren't certificates bound to these ports. You can [Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate). You can also refer to [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833235/ssl-certificate-add-failed-error-183-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-alrea?rq=1)

certhash=***. The certhash parameter specifies the thumbprint of the certificate. [Retrieve the Thumbprint of a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-retrieve-the-thumbprint-of-a-certificate)